# JSON in a R list form to single merged dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently am connecting to a mongodb through the rmongodb package (which isnt necessary for this example), it provides me with a list in the form of "mongo_data" list supplied in the code below. I want to take a list in this format and end up with a single dataframe. I currently use a loop (which I have setup to run in parallel but even still it is quite slow when using large amounts of data. Any ideas on how to do this without using a loop?

**Reproducible data**

```
symbols <- c("SPXT", "BCOM", "MXWO")

mongo_data <- list(structure(list(`_id` = "561369b8e756f3e744d9d697", symbol = "BCOM", 
    year = 2014, field = "PX_LAST", monthly = list(structure(list(
        `2014-01-31` = 126.1206, `2014-02-28` = 133.9783, `2014-03-31` = 134.5234, 
        `2014-04-30` = 137.7964, `2014-05-30` = 133.8324, `2014-06-30` = 134.6268, 
        `2014-07-31` = 127.9143, `2014-08-29` = 126.5745, `2014-09-30` = 118.6922, 
        `2014-10-31` = 117.7365, `2014-11-28` = 112.9451, `2014-12-31` = 104.3285), .Names = c("2014-01-31", 
    "2014-02-28", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-30", "2014-06-30", 
    "2014-07-31", "2014-08-29", "2014-09-30", "2014-10-31", "2014-11-28", 
    "2014-12-31")))), .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "field", 
"monthly")), structure(list(`_id` = "561369b8e756f3e744d9d698", 
    symbol = "BCOM", year = 2015, field = "PX_LAST", monthly = list(
        structure(list(`2015-01-30` = 100.8413, `2015-02-27` = 103.4379, 
            `2015-03-31` = 98.123, `2015-04-30` = 103.7471, `2015-05-29` = 100.9465, 
            `2015-06-30` = 102.6892, `2015-07-31` = 91.7827, 
            `2015-08-31` = 90.9328, `2015-09-30` = 87.8214), .Names = c("2015-01-30", 
        "2015-02-27", "2015-03-31", "2015-04-30", "2015-05-29", 
        "2015-06-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-08-31", "2015-09-30"
        )))), .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "field", "monthly"
)), structure(list(`_id` = "561353f1e756f3e744d97955", symbol = "MXWO", 
    year = 2014, field = "PX_LAST", monthly = list(structure(list(
        `2014-01-31` = 1598.46, `2014-02-28` = 1675.4, `2014-03-31` = 1673.87, 
        `2014-04-30` = 1687.74, `2014-05-30` = 1715.18, `2014-06-30` = 1743.42, 
        `2014-07-31` = 1714.35, `2014-08-29` = 1748.69, `2014-09-30` = 1698.41, 
        `2014-10-31` = 1708.09, `2014-11-28` = 1739.5, `2014-12-31` = 1709.67), .Names = c("2014-01-31", 
    "2014-02-28", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-30", "2014-06-30", 
    "2014-07-31", "2014-08-29", "2014-09-30", "2014-10-31", "2014-11-28", 
    "2014-12-31")))), .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "field", 
"monthly")), structure(list(`_id` = "561353f1e756f3e744d97956", 
    symbol = "MXWO", year = 2015, field = "PX_LAST", monthly = list(
        structure(list(`2015-01-30` = 1677.54, `2015-02-27` = 1772.86, 
            `2015-03-31` = 1740.81, `2015-04-30` = 1778.4, `2015-05-29` = 1779.31, 
            `2015-06-30` = 1735.61, `2015-07-31` = 1765.6, `2015-08-31` = 1645.43, 
            `2015-09-30` = 1581.92), .Names = c("2015-01-30", 
        "2015-02-27", "2015-03-31", "2015-04-30", "2015-05-29", 
        "2015-06-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-08-31", "2015-09-30"
        )))), .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "field", "monthly"
)), structure(list(`_id` = "5613542fe756f3e744d97a69", symbol = "SPXT", 
    year = 2014, field = "PX_LAST", monthly = list(structure(list(
        `2014-01-31` = 3200.95, `2014-02-28` = 3347.3799, `2014-03-31` = 3375.51, 
        `2014-04-30` = 3400.46, `2014-05-30` = 3480.29, `2014-06-30` = 3552.1799, 
        `2014-07-31` = 3503.1899, `2014-08-29` = 3643.3401, `2014-09-30` = 3592.25, 
        `2014-10-31` = 3679.99, `2014-11-28` = 3778.96, `2014-12-31` = 3769.4399), .Names = c("2014-01-31", 
    "2014-02-28", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-30", "2014-06-30", 
    "2014-07-31", "2014-08-29", "2014-09-30", "2014-10-31", "2014-11-28", 
    "2014-12-31")))), .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "field", 
"monthly")), structure(list(`_id` = "5613542fe756f3e744d97a6a", 
    symbol = "SPXT", year = 2015, field = "PX_LAST", monthly = list(
        structure(list(`2015-01-30` = 3656.28, `2015-02-27` = 3866.4199, 
            `2015-03-31` = 3805.27, `2015-04-30` = 3841.78, `2015-05-29` = 3891.1799, 
            `2015-06-30` = 3815.8501, `2015-07-31` = 3895.8, 
            `2015-08-31` = 3660.75, `2015-09-30` = 3570.1699), .Names = c("2015-01-30", 
        "2015-02-27", "2015-03-31", "2015-04-30", "2015-05-29", 
        "2015-06-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-08-31", "2015-09-30"
        )))), .Names = c("_id", "symbol", "year", "field", "monthly"
)))
```

**Code Using Currently**

```
library(foreach)
 library(doParallel)

    cl <- makeCluster((detectCores()))
    registerDoParallel(cl)


    total_df_list <- foreach(i=(1:length(symbols))) %dopar% {
      # pull out the data for symbol i
      symbol_data <- mongo_data[which(sapply(lapply(mongo_data, "[[", "symbol"), function(x) x == symbols[i]))]
      # pull out the particular frequency of data & put into a single list
      freq_data <- lapply(symbol_data, "[[", "monthly")
      freq_data <- do.call(Map, c(c, freq_data))
      # if the frequency doesnt exist then add symbol to filler vector
      if (length(freq_data) > 0) {
        # convert NULLs to NAs
        freq_data[[1]][which(sapply(freq_data[[1]], is.null))] <- NA
        # transform list into a proper dataframe
        mongo_df <- data.frame("Date" = names(unlist(freq_data[[1]])),"Value"=as.numeric(unlist(freq_data[[1]])))
        mongo_df[,"Date"] <- as.Date(mongo_df[,"Date"])
        colnames(mongo_df)[2] <- paste0(symbols[i])
        # put dataframe into the master list
        results <- mongo_df
      } else {
        filler_vector <- c(filler_vector,symbols[i])
        results <- NULL
      }
      results
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some benchmarking of my previous solution for this question, and I noticed that nearly all the runtime was spent in the `as.Date` call, which converts string dates to `Date` objects. As a result, it seems like optimizing this operation would be needed to further push the efficiency. One observation would be that many of the dates are reported multiple times (for different symbols), so we are wasting computation by performing date conversions for the same string literal multiple times. To address this, we could use the following procedure:

1. Compute all unique date strings
2. Convert them to `Date` objects with `as.Date`
3. Look up the converted value for each date string, yielding the final converted vector

In code, we could do this with:

```
vals <- unlist(lapply(mongo_data, "[[", "monthly"))
s <- unlist(lapply(mongo_data, function(x) rep(x$symbol, length(x$monthly[[1]]))))
dates <- unique(names(vals))
date.map <- as.Date(dates)
names(date.map) <- dates
partial <- data.frame(Date=date.map[names(vals)], val=as.numeric(vals),
                      symbol=s)
tdl2 <- unname(lapply(split(partial, partial$s), function(x) {
  names(x)[2] <- as.character(x$symbol[1])
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x[,-3]
})[symbols])
identical(total_df_list, tdl2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Let's benchmark this on a large instance that is obtained by repeating each row in `mongo_data` 10,000 times. `OP` is the function from the original question, `josilber1` is from my other answer, and `josilber2` is from this answer:

```
big.mongo <- mongo_data[rep(seq_along(mongo_data), 10000)]
system.time(OP(big.mongo, symbols))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   5.359   0.071   5.427 
system.time(josilber1(big.mongo, symbols))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.345   0.047   4.385 
system.time(josilber2(big.mongo, symbols))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.560   0.048   0.625
```

My other answer yielded a 20% improvement in the runtime, while this solution yielded roughly a 10x speedup.

Comment: Im very impressed, I will definitely start to benchmark different parts of a task in the future to figure out where the bottlenecks truly are. I never would have guessed as.Date would be the slow part, just goes to show you... Thank you for the code, it makes complete sense (in general doing the unique and looking up since its vectorized at that point should be fast, logical to me).

Answer (score 1):

I see a few opportunities to speed this up:

1. Don't loop through the list extracting the symbol name for each symbol you process. Instead you can extract all the symbol names at the beginning and use that to quickly identify the part of the list you want to process.
2. `sapply` with `==` to look up matching symbols is calling `==` separately on each element. It would be more efficient to just call `==` once on the whole vector.
3. `sapply` with `is.null` is calling `is.null` separately on each element. It would be more efficient to just call `is.null` once on the whole vector.

Here's my updated implementation:

```
mongo.sym <- unlist(lapply(mongo_data, "[[", "symbol"))
tdl <- lapply(symbols, function(sym) {
  vals <- unlist(lapply(mongo_data[mongo.sym == sym], function(x) unlist(x$monthly)))
  vals[is.null(vals)] <- NA
  ret <- data.frame(as.Date(names(vals)), as.numeric(vals))
  names(ret) <- c("Date", sym)
  ret
})
identical(total_df_list, tdl)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow I dont even know where to start, thank you. I keep forgetting I can setup a lapply function like that to wrap various tasks, need to rely on that more. Also the vectorized parts that were possible to do at once you pulled out, makes a lot of sense. Thanks again.